# Sort Excel columns through COM from LotusScript

Tags: vba, com, lotusscript

I have a LotusScript agent that creates an Excel spreadsheet from Notes documents, with five columns, like this:

```
Vendor Name  Plan Year   Plan Month   Project Name       Store
Advantage    2013        2            Dairy_BiProducts   136
Kraft        2013        2            Dairy_BiProducts   330
Daymon       2013        2            Dairy_BiProducts   382
Advantage    2013        2            Dairy_BiProducts   398
Daymon       2013        2            Dairy_BiProducts   616
Advantage    2013        2            Dairy_BiProducts   691
```

The following line sorts the sheet:

```
sheet.Columns.EntireColumn.Sort sheet.Cells(2, 1), 1, , , , , , 1, 1, False, 1,
```

and ends up giving me the first and second columns sorted (although at the moment the second column contains "2013" all the way down, so I don't know if that line of code is or is not sorting that column).

I got everything from `Sort` to the end of the line from [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/46dom.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/68245b4d051ff2b585256c090020480b?OpenDocument), but I can't find any documentation for the method signature, so I have no idea what each argument stands for, and how to change it to sort spreadsheet the way I want.  All the documentation I can find is for using the *Sort* method directly from VB, which seems to work differently.

I'd like to sort each of the 5 columns: first the first column, then the second, etc.  How can I do this?

Comment: hover over the word .Sort in the VBE and press F1. It will tell you the parameters with descriptions. Alternatively, right click .Sort and select "Definition". This will open up the object browser and show you all the parameters, and allow you to 'click through' any enums etc. For absolutely minimal info of param names and types, just right click and select "Quick Info", or temporarily open a bracket after Sort (like `.Sort(`)

Comment: ah sorry, just realised this isn't from the VBE. Well, assuming it is just a pass-through to VBA or something similar (like via PIAs) then the easiest is to open up excel and have a look. Alternatively, MSDN does have a reference library too (you are looking for Range.Sort method: native VBA here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213557%28v=office.11%29.aspx or through Office PIAs here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.sort.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, one or both of those links mentioned the Cells(x,y) syntax being acceptable as the first argument, which I had not seen previously.  So apparently it is closer to the normal VBA syntax than I'd realized.

Comment: the first argument takes any Range (amongst other things). Cells(x,y) returns a single-cell range. When VBA gets a single cell range in the .Sort method, it reads that as a sign to apply the sort to `CurrentRegion` area of Cells. In practice this means what the range of cells that would be selected by pressing Cntrl+A once, and covers all cells with values until it reaches a break of empty cells. If you think you will have empty cells in the range you want to sort, then try and pass in the full range instead to prevent it missing cells that you actually wanted sorted.

Comment: What if there's an empty cell in one column but the rest of the row is not empty?  Does it still sort properly?

Comment: yep, it should do. CurrentRegion continues expanding until it reaches a complete break in cells. (visualise it that it continues expanding from the origin in a rectangle consuming all cells until no cell within the area has any filled cells adjacent to it at at which point it stops).

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to record this operation in excel and look in the created macro?

`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D3:D8"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E3:E8"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F3:F8"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("G3:G8"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal`

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("D3:G8")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```